# Adding Primefaces components dynamically

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, selectonemenu

I want to add Primefaces components dynamically. I'm using solution similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046116/can-i-add-remove-primefaces-components-dynamically), which was discussed there earlier:

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:dataGrid id="categoriesGrid" value="#{bean.categories}"
            var="categoryBean" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="categorySelect" effect="drop"
                    value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.availableCategories}"
                        var="category" itemLabel="#{category.name}"
                        itemValue="#{category}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataGrid>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.addNewCategory}"
            value="Add category" update="categoriesGrid"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

But there is problem with it. There is example of respond I get after "Add category" button was clicked:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
<error>
    <error-name>
        class javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException
    </error-name>
    <error-message>
        <![CDATA[/createTutorial.xhtml @85,65 value=
            "#{categoryBean.selectedCategory}":java.util.NoSuchElementException]]>
    </error-message>
</error>
</partial-response>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I found [there](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1568), `p:column` must be added, but the problem with ajax still exist

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (which you can accept later yourself).

Comment: Do not put "Solved" in title. Post an **answer** and mark it accepted. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my bean. In order to get selected item, I had to implement custom implementation of `javax.faces.Converter` interface. In my opinion it's quite much work to do for such simple problem (this converter must be able to have access to data source and so on). So I've made a little trick:

```
public class CategoryBean{

    private list<Category> availableCategories;
    private Category selectedCategory;

    public Long getCSelectedCategory(){
        // Get selected category by it's id and set selectedCategory
    }

    public void setSelectedCategory(Long selectedCategory){
        return selectedCategory.getId();
    }

    // The remaining setters and getters
}
```

And the corresponding piece of page code now looks like:

```xml
<p:column>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="categorySelect" effect="drop"
        value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.availableCategories}"
            var="category" itemLabel="#{category.name}"
            itemValue="#{category.id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
```

Please, pay your attention to the `itemValue` attribute and access methods that are shown.The bug I had  was wrong getter return type.

**Concluding**, the only problem with adding new Primefaces components dynamically in my case was returning selected value. You may implement converter or use similar trick.

Is such trick a good solution in your opinion?

Comment: If this is your final code then it does not look good and your trick is not a good trick. Because, if you take a look at this `value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory}"` and this `itemValue="#{category.id}"`, it looks confusing. I think it's a good practice to use a converter in such a case.